# Can soap kill cockroaches and/or ants? If so, how?

Tags: cell-biology, zoology, entomology, toxicology, biochemistry

Is it possible to use dishwashing soap as an alternative insecticide? How would that and what are the components of the dishwashing soap that would kill the insect?

Comment: please read the help pages before posting questions

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely confident that the aforementioned post is a duplicate, because the question explicitly asks "Why do cockroaches **burst** from soapy water?" While this question explicitly asks "**Can** soap kill cockroaches **and/or ants**?"

The short answer to your question is **yes**.

According to [this website](http://www.wikihow.com/Get-Rid-of-Roaches):

> The soapy water kills [cockroaches] by forming a thin film over the
>   roach's breathing pores that stays in place due to surface tension,
>   causing the roach to suffocate.

Ants are killed in a similar manner (see [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/2hjuwl/eli5_why_does_a_soapwater_mixture_kill_ants/) archived Reddit post).

For a more scientific read, check out this paper: [Behavioral Responses and Mortality in German Cockroaches (Blattodea: Blattellidae) After Exposure to Dishwashing Liquid.](https://jee.oxfordjournals.org/content/95/2/390.abstract)